# What is a Limit or Limiting-value?

Tags: limits

As far as I understand, the following is my personal definition for limits/limiting-values:

> If the value of a function cannot be determined for any value of the independent variable, then, the value the function seems to be approaching would be its limiting value for that particular value of the independent variable.
>
> For instance, $f(x)=\frac{2x}{x+1}$'s limiting value is $2$ at $\infty$ as we can't determine the value of $f(x)$ at $x=\infty$. But, it seems that $f(x)$ is approaching $2$ when $x$ approaches $\infty$.
>   [image]

**Am I correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to your first claim "*If the value of a function cannot be determined for any value of the independent variable $\ldots$*", as noticed in the comments by T.Bongers, recall that the limit at a point has nothing to do with the existence of a value for the funcion at that point.

For example we know that $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not defined at $x=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ holds even if we define, for example, $\frac{\sin x}{x}=\pi$ at $x=0$.

When at a point $x=x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ the limit value coincides with the value of the funtion at that point we define the function continuous at that point, that is

$$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=f(x_0) \iff \text{f is continuous at x=x_0}$$

With reference to the example, your rough idea  "*(seems) that $f(x)$ is approaching 2 when $x$ approaches $\infty$*" is correct, even if not rigorous of course.

More precisely we could say that the function approaches $2$ closer and closer as $x$ becomes larger and in a rigorous way we say that

$$\forall \epsilon >0 \quad \exists \bar x \quad \forall x>\bar x \quad |f(x)-2|<\epsilon$$

that is

- for any fixed "small" number $\epsilon >0$
- (at least) a value $\bar x$ exists such that for any $x$ larger than $\bar x$ (i.e."eventually")
- $f(x)$ approches the value $2$ with a difference less than $\epsilon$

Comment: I do not agree that the rough idea is correct. The limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ has nothing to do with trying to "determine the value of $f(x)$ at $x = \infty$" as stated in the question, just as $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ is not about computing $f(0)$ in general (plus the added issue of confusing $\infty$ as a number...).This is a very common mistake that students make that should be addressed.

Comment: @T.Bongers The rough idea I was referring to is "(seems) that $f(x)$ is approaching 2 when $x$ approaches $\infty$" with reference to the specific example for $x \to \infty$. Maybe I should clarify that.

Comment: @yahoo.com I've added a word explanation for the notation, what is not clear?

Comment: @yahoo.com At some point, you're going to need to learn how to read and interpret formal notation. If you limit yourself to vague and informal understanding of the concepts, that is going to seriously limit your understanding of the mathematics.

Comment: @yahoo.com The formal language is necessary to express the concept properly, you should make an effort to understand that it is not so difficult, you only need some practice!

Comment: @yahoo.com: I think your issue is not so much about formalism, but rather you want to avoid rigor. You may get rid of formalism by using English words instead of math symbols. But rigor part is not optional here.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, a very little space for free advice.